# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll C3 Discord.NET bot

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, discord.net

Everytime I try to run a command though my discord.NET C# bot that sends an image I get this error message

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
```

I don't know what is causing this, because I have refrenched it a few times.

Collection of screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfRIF.jpg

I am using discord.NET 0.9.6

EDIT: I WAS BEING A DINGUS AND USED .png INSTEAD OF .jpg IN CODE!! (Still a coding nub and need to work on mah debuggin' :D)

Comment: Sounds like your image paths are wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve this System.IO.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774135/how-to-resolve-this-system-io-filenotfoundexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have files of *.jpg type in img folder and referred as *.png in code.

Comment: Thanks alot, I changed the extention when I added them so I didn't notice :D