# C# compiled .exe System.IO.FileNotFOundException

Tags: c#, windows

(Environment = Windows 10 1803, program type is .exe)

I have written a program to be used across different computers at work, however, When i try to run the compile program from anyone elses machine other than my own (and my fellow IT coworkers), I end up with this error:

(From event viewer)

> Event 1026, .NET Runtime Application: program123.exe Framework Version
>   v4.0.30.319 Description: The process was terminated due to an
>   unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName,
>   System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence,
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, ........

I have extensive logging in the application and pretty much log immediately upon program entry. However, my log never gets hit - (to me, this means that this application is being blocked, or dying before running any code).

This is different because my application does not even start. In the example that you recommended, the application begins and then fails on an event. My .exe will not work at all.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the right .Net framework runtime installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve this System.IO.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774135/how-to-resolve-this-system-io-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: @OwenPauling, The answer on that post does not apply to my situation ( I do not believe) I have checked all of the paths looking for any absolutes and as I said above, I do not believe that the application even reaches the entry point before it dies. The very first line of code logs information to the desktop (for debugging purposes) and it never gets hit.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes they have the correct runtime