# How to handle URI activation in a Windows Application Packaging Project?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I have a WPF application and I'm making a UWP app using the desktop bridge. Basically I created a new Windows App Packaging Project and I added to it my WPF project as a reference. I added a Protocol declaration in the app manifest with a custom URI, but I can't implement/override the `OnActivated()` method, because I have no classes where to do it and it isn't even possible to add classes to this type of project. So, any ideas how can I handle my custom URI calls in this environment?

I already create another UWP project, which just handles these requests and I also added this project to the main packaging project as a reference. Basically it's working, but if I create the app package and I install it (the appxbundle), then the URI handler won't be called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1) The protocol activation arguments are passed to your app's main() function. However, since you are using WPF you need to first understand how to get to your main() function. This is explained in this answer:
[No Main() in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694680/no-main-in-wpf)

2) A better approach is available with the current Windows SDK (1809 and later): You can call this new method to the get activation arguments for your packaged WPF app (or any packaged Win32 app):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinstance.getactivatedeventargs#Windows_ApplicationModel_AppInstance_GetActivatedEventArgs

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for how to handle URI activation for a .NET7 WPF project.  The accepted answer here was the best advice I found but didn't work for my use case.

Here's what I had to do:

## Install Protocol

- Create a Windows Application Project for my WPF app, including the protocol details
- Build and install to install the protocol
- Launch using the protocol from the Windows Run dialog to confirm the install

## Debugging protocol launch / Uri Activation

There doesn't seem to be a way to target the debug app with the installed protocol (at least as gracefully as UWP does).  After failing to find any docs I found (through experimentation) that launching the app through the protocol passes the URI in the args passed to `App.OnStartup`.

To debug protocol launches then, you need to add command line arguments to your Launch Profile.  This is done through the startup project's properties in Solution Explorer under `Debug | General` (see image).

Now you can hit `F5` in Visual Studio and debug your URI Activation.

[image]